elastic beanstalk npm ERR! nest-server@0.0.1 start: `NO_COLOR=true NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main`
I recently uploaded a new version of the application,I’m using Elastic Beanstalk for my API. and the upload was successful. However, the API isn’t loading. Could you please help me troubleshoot this issue? Since I’m new to AWS, I would appreciate a step-by-step guide on how to address it .I am just get handed this project from other developer team .
This is the error from web.stdout.log
npm ERR! nest-server@0.0.1 start: `NO_COLOR=true NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main`

i guess to look package.json but don't know how to change it
  "name": "nest-server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=7.0.0",
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "NO_COLOR=true NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "NO_COLOR=true NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main",
    "start:prod-local": "ALLOW_ALL=true NODE_ENV=prod nest start",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "deploy": "npm run build && eb deploy"
  },


I understand the frustration of not even knowing where to start. However, SO is not the best place for such vague questions either. What does it mean "the API is not loading"?The "error" message does not say anything useful either. Is that all there is? More context is required. Can you launch the API locally? Are you able to break down this problem into smaller questions? There could be so many different reasons why you're facing issues.
